# MVC/WebApi: Exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' - When retrieving array from post request

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am learning how to send within a POST, two parameters grouped in an object array as payload.

AngularJS:

```
var parData = { 'panelists': JSON.stringify($scope.arr), 'id': $scope.webId };
                
$http.post("/api/addPanelists", parData)
    .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
}), function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("An error occurred during the request");
};
```

Server Side:

Class Panelists:

```
public class Panelists
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

AddPanelists ApiController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void CreatePanelists(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject data)
    {
       
        List<Panelists_DataImport.Panelist> panelistList = new List<Panelists_DI.Panelist>();
        panelistList = data["panelist"].ToObject<List<Panelists_DataImport.Panelist>>();
        webID = data["webId"].ToObject<Panelists_DataImport.Webinar>();

    }
```

data contents:

```
{{  "panelists": "[{\"name\":\"Jack Anderson\",\"email\":\"janderson@email.com\"},{\"name\":\"Ed Johnson\",\"email\":\"ejohnson@email.com\"},{\"name\":\"Dead Poole\",\"email\":\"dpoole@email.com\"},{\"name\":\"Hank  Schmidt\",\"email\":\"hschmidt@email.com\"},{\"name\":\"Steven Alves\",\"email\":\"salves@email.com\"}]",  "id": "94395753143"}}
```

When I get to the line

```
panelistList = data["panelists"].ToObject<List<Panelists>>();
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error converting value "[{"name":"Jack Anderson","email":"janderson@email.com"},{"name":"Ed Johnson","email":"ejohnson@email.com"},{"name":"Dead Poole","email":"dpoole@email.com"},{"name":"Hank  Schmidt","email":"hschmidt@email.com"},{"name":"Steven Alves","email":"salves@email.com"}]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Panelists_DataImport.Panelists]'. Path ''.
```

How can I correctly retrieve the array from the post request?
Am I using the incorrect type?

I am stuck at the moment and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Erasmo

**UPDATE CODE**
*(not working not yet understanding how to implement from article)*

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void CreatePanelists(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject data)
    {

        string webID = data["id"].ToString();

        IList<Panelist> panelistList = new IList<Panelist>;
    }

    public class Panelist
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parameters
    {
        public IList<Panelist> panelists { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

UPDATE with screen shots of new code and error window:

[image: code]

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something wrong here.

Valid JSON will be

```
{
    "panelists": [{
        "name": "Jack Anderson",
        "email": "janderson@email.com"
    }, {
        "name": "Ed Johnson",
        "email": "ejohnson@email.com"
    }, {
        "name": "Dead Poole",
        "email": "dpoole@email.com"
    }, {
        "name": "Hank  Schmidt",
        "email": "hschmidt@email.com"
    }, {
        "name": "Steven Alves",
        "email": "salves@email.com"
    }],
    "id": "94395753143"
}
```

and class should be like this.

```
public class Panelist
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public IList<Panelist> panelists { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

and you should access it like this.

`data.panelists` not like this `data["panelists"]`

Update:

```
[HttpPost]
public void CreatePanelists(string data)
{

    Parameters parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parameters>(data);

    IList<Panelist> panelistList = parameters.panelists;
}
```

Comment: Hello @vivek nuna - Thank you for your answer. I hope I'm not asking much, would it be possible to show me how to implement your suggestion within the code I provided? I think it would be easier for me to learn that way. Thank you again.

Comment: @erasmocarlos please see this example, its very easy https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: If not like this data["panelists"], why webID = data["webId"].ToObject<Panelists_DataImport.Webinar>(); works well?

Comment: No I am trying but I am not getting it. I'm sorry

Comment: uppdate the question with your latest code and error details and update me then

Comment: I did. Sorry for not being more fast to understand the code.

Comment: @erasmocarlos check the update section in my answer

Comment: I grabbed your code example and placed it in my project. The syntax does not seem to be correct, other errors are appearing now. I am not following this right. I updated with screen shot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216735/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-erasmo-carlos).